# Update multiple rows with subquery from tables with no relation

Tags: mysql

Given the following table structure:

```
  nodes              import
========         ==============
id | val         node_id | name
--------         --------------
...|             ...     |
45 | a           NULL    | ...
51 | b           NULL    | ...
99 | c           NULL    | ...
...              ...
```

How can I update the `NULL` `node_id` fields in the `import` table with  with the `id's` from the `nodes` table?

For example, the `NULL` fields must be updated by all `id's` > 44. (The order does not matter)

It is guaranteed that the number of `NULL's` will match the number of `id's` > 44.

**There is no relation between other fields in the tables.**

**The tables (and updates) are expected to contain 10s of millions of rows, and the query needs to be as efficient as possible**

Comment: Questions:
1) In your import table, are all records having NULL node_id value?
2) Are there any values in "name" field?
3) If there is no relation between the two tables (and there won't be relation after the update), why do you need to update the node_id with id values?
4) Is there any connection between nodes.val and import.name?

The way I see it, if your import table is empty, you can just make an sqldump of the nodes table and load back into import table.

Comment: @Amao Mao
1) Some are NULL, others have values.
2) Yes, there are values in the name field.
3) I generate new nodes in the node table, and then need to assign those new node_ids to rows in import table.
4) No relation at all.
5) The table is not empty, but a sqldump might be an option to investigate.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I'm glad that helps. For non-related reports you can't just update a table with values from another, like this case if you want to update from node to import, you can't as your import table has nothing unique to identify which row it got updated.